# itemClickListener not working using databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am trying to implement recyclerView with help of viewModel, model and databinging,but when i try to get click for each item click is not getting triggered. Here is the code i used for getting item click from recyclerView.

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="recordedItem"
        type="com.mi.data.model.RecordedVideoListItem" />

   
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.mi.ui.recordVideoUi.RecordedVideoViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:onClick="@{(view)->viewModel.clickONBtn(view,recordedItem)}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_150"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_8"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_8">.....
```

And inside viewModel

```
  fun clickONBtn(view: View, item: RecordedVideoListItem) {
    view.context.toast(wifiPojo.title!!)
    Log.d("MyTag", "clicked on${item.title}")
}
```

But no log or toast is showing when i clicked on each item. can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I am not sure that point towards your viewmodel is the best practice here. I am saying that because I dont have a working sample like you are doing, but I have some importing a regular class and doing what you are doing. Have you considered to instead of viewmodel, do it with a regular class?

Comment: If you are correctly binding the list item in your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` subclass, (e.g.  `binding.setRecordedItem()`), you can simply do `android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.clickONBtn(recordedItem)}"` in your `xml` file.

If you really need to pass the view model, make sure you are setting it correctly in your binding method, too.

Place a breakpoint in your `clickONBtn()` method, see if it's being called at all